# Display a random number 25 times with a 320ms delay Js

Tags: javascript, html, random, numbers

I have been trying to find a answer for this but I couldn't really get it to work.
I need JavaScript code to display a random number 25 times with a 320ms delay for each number.
(Ignore the other things except for //start roll)

```
    function roll() {

var win = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 0
//change the button when rolling
rollButton.disabled = true;
rollButton.innerHTML = "Rolling...";
rollButton.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
rollButton.style.color = "black"
setTimeout(unDisable, 8000)
//start roll
(insert code here)


}
```

Thanks if you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple thing you can do is simply:

```js
function roll() {
    //change the button when rolling
    rollButton.disabled = true;
    rollButton.innerHTML = "Rolling...";
    rollButton.style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    rollButton.style.color = "black"
    setTimeout(unDisable, 8000)
    //start roll
    showNum(25)
}
const getRand = _ => Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + 0
const showNum = n => {
  if (n-- <= 0) {return}
  document.getElementById("dispNum").innerHTML = getRand()
  setTimeout(_ => showNum(n), 320)
}
```

It will keep spawning a new thread to print a random number while decrementing its iteration count, till it hits `0`

Comment: Can you write the code so it prints a random number 0-24 to: document.getElementById("dispNum").innerHTML

Comment: Nice! It works now! Thanks so much guys you are a life saver

Comment: If it helped, make sure to upvote and mark as Accepted, so other people can benefit from the answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` for make loop with some delay and `clearInterval` for stopping that loop !

```js
$(function(){

t = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  var win = Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) ;
  var html = $('span').html();
  $('span').html(html + win + '<br>')
  t++;
  if(t == 25)
    stop();
}, 320);
function stop(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
```